# Android Preference Screen without XML

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I want to create a preferences screen without writing an XML layout file. I'd like to store the settings in a SQLite database. Is this possible?

Comment: How would your preferences screen know what to display, then?

Comment: If you don't want to use XML, don't want to use PreferenceManager, and want to store your own records, why not just make your own Activity, altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a preference hierarchy (probably in `onCreate()` for the `PreferenceFragment`) with:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = new PreferenceScreen();
```

and add preference items to `screen` using `addPreference`. In the `PreferenceFragment` (or `PreferenceActivity`, if you aren't using fragments), just call `setPreferenceScreen` with the hierarchy after it's constructed.

Comment: Sorry... i want to say that i I want to create a preferences screen without writing an XML settings file because i want to store all in my custom db sqlite.

Comment: @user1798790 - Why would you want to use an sqlite db instead of the built-in preferences storage system? It makes it harder to access the preference settings from elsewhere in your program and you lose the ability to listen for setting changes. (Plus, you then have to do a lot of other work because you can't simply use a `PreferenceActivity`.)

Comment: I would use only the GUi of preference screen and interface it with the db.non want the information to be saved in the xml file.thank